# Debug of output in ansible fails with error

Tags: ansible

I am using following playbook

```yaml
---
- name: ""
  hosts: nexus
  tasks:
    - name: ""
      debug:
        var="{{ vlans | map(attribute='vlan_id') | join(',')  }}"
```

and the output is:

```
ok: [nx01] => {
    "10,20,100,30": "(10, 20, 100, 30)"
}
```

What is the type of my output ?

I tried

```yaml
---
- name: ""
  hosts: nexus
  tasks:
    - name: ""
      debug:
        var="{{ vlans | map(attribute='vlan_id') | join(',') | type_debug }} "
```

but get an error

```
ok: [nx02] => {
    "str ": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Comment: `var` option to `debug` is to debug a var content directly giving its name. Here you want, you want to use the `msg` option. Read the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```yaml
    - name: Create a string with vlans
      debug:
        msg:
          "{{ vlans | map(attribute = 'vlan_id') | join(',') }}"

    - name: Create a string with vlans | type_debug
      debug:
        msg:
          "{{ vlans | map(attribute = 'vlan_id') | join(',') | type_debug }}"
```

output:

```
TASK [Create a string with vlans] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10,20,100,30"
}

TASK [Create a string with vlans | type_debug] *************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "str"
}
```

The same example with list:

```yaml
    - name: Create a list with vlans
      debug:
        msg:
          "{{ vlans | map(attribute = 'vlan_id') | list | default([]) }}"

    - name: Create a string with vlans | type_debug
      debug:
        msg:
          "{{ vlans | map(attribute = 'vlan_id') | list | default([]) | type_debug }}"
```

And the Output:

```
TASK [Create a list with vlans] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        10,
        20,
        100,
        30
    ]
}

TASK [Create a string with vlans | type_debug] ************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "list"
}
```

And if you need to set a variable:

```yaml
    - name: Set variable
      set_fact:
        mystrvar: "{{ vlans | map(attribute = 'vlan_id') | join(',') }}"
        mylistvar: "{{ vlans | map(attribute = 'vlan_id') | list | default([]) }}"

    - name: Debug mystrvar
      debug:
        var: mystrvar

    - name: Debug mystrvar
      debug:
        var: mystrvar | type_debug

    - name: Debug mylistvar
      debug:
        var: mylistvar

    - name: Debug mylistvar
      debug:
        var: mylistvar | type_debug
```

The output:

```
TASK [Set variable] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug mystrvar] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
   "mystrvar": "10,20,100,30"
}

TASK [Debug mystrvar] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
   "mystrvar | type_debug": "str"
}

TASK [Debug mylistvar] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mylistvar": [
        10,
        20,
        100,
        30
    ]
}

TASK [Debug mylistvar] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mylistvar | type_debug": "list"
}
```